# Is it possible to create a polynomial through Numpy's C API?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I'm using SWIG to wrap a C++ library with its own polynomial type. I'd like to create a typemap to automatically convert that to a numpy polynomial. However, browsing the docs for the numpy C API, I'm not seeing anything that would allow me to do this, only numpy arrays. Is it possible to typemap to a polynomial?

Comment: Which numpy polynomial do you have in mind.  There is a simple `np.poly1d` class, but that's pure Python.  It contains the coefficients and some display information.  The rest is evaluation methods.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm looking at (sigh) `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial`. Did some more research, and it looks like I can just convert the coefficients to a ndarray and just use that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy's polynomial package is largely a collection of functions that can accept array-like objects as the polynomial. Therefore, it is sufficient to convert to a normal ndarray, where the value at index n is the coefficient for the term with exponent n.